# Change wavetable pitch (Resample)

Tags: java, math, audio

I've been using math equations to do some basic synthesis for android. The problem with that the formulas keep and keep getting more complicated. So i'm starting to use wavetable synthesis.

So far i can play a single note based on an array of bytes and a predetermined frequency. However when looking for formulas to resample the samples and change the pitch of the wavetable... i just couldn't find a simple solution. There are whole libraries that do this. But it feels like it should be a simple formula to change the sample frequency by downsampling or oversampling.

Is there an easy way of doing that?

Ex: Input is `[0,0.5,1,0.5,0...]` let's pretend it's a C4

To make it a C3 the expected output should be `[0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,0.75,0.5,0.25,0...]`

Basically it's and android's audiopool "rate" property but just the formula that resamples the bytes, which i haven't found anywhere

EDIT:

Thank you to Phil Freihofner for guiding me to the answer. However the original formula he provided didn't smoothed out the end in case of oversampling. But it was a really nice start and i only had to smooth the end. I will attach my end code in case anyone wants a simple function to "Stretch out" a float array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] sample = {0f, 0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, 0f, 0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, 0};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resample(sample, 2f)));
        //[0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resample(sample, 3f)));
        //[0.0, 0.16666667, 0.33333334, 0.5, 0.6666667, 0.8333333, 1.0, 0.8333334, 0.6666666, 0.5, 0.33333337, 0.16666663, 0.0, 0.16666675, 0.33333325, 0.5, 0.66666675, 0.83333325, 1.0, 0.83333325, 0.66666675, 0.5, 0.33333325, 0.16666675, 0.111111164, 0.055555582, 0.0]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resample(sample, 0.5f)));
        //[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resample(sample, 1f)));
        //[0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resample(sample, 4.3f)));
        //[0.0, 0.116279066, 0.23255813, 0.3488372, 0.46511626, 0.5813953, 0.6976744, 0.81395346, 0.9302325, 0.95348847, 0.83720934, 0.72093034, 0.6046512, 0.4883722, 0.37209308, 0.25581408, 0.13953495, 0.023255944, 0.09302306, 0.20930219, 0.3255813, 0.44186044, 0.5581393, 0.67441845, 0.7906976, 0.9069767, 0.9767444, 0.8604653, 0.74418616, 0.62790704, 0.51162815, 0.39534903, 0.2790699, 0.16279078, 0.04651189, 0.034883916, 0.023255944, 0.011627972, 0.0]
    }

    public static float[] resample(float[] sample, float rate) {
        if (rate == 1) {
            return sample;
        }
        int newLength = Math.round(sample.length * rate); 
        int rateUnit = (int) Math.round(rate);
        float[] result = new float[newLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < newLength - rateUnit; i++) {
            float val = (i / rate);
            int o = (int) val;
            result[i] = sample[o + 1] * (val - o)
                    + sample[o] * ((o + 1) - val);
        }
        int startIndex = newLength - rateUnit;

        for (int u = 0; u < newLength - startIndex; u++) {
            result[startIndex + u] = result[startIndex - 1] + (u + 1) * 
                    (sample[sample.length - 1] - result[startIndex - 1]) / rateUnit;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a wave table in floats.

What you can then do is create a "cursor" to iterate through the table. This cursor does NOT have to be an integer, it can be a float. When your cursor lands on a value that is in between two elements your wave table, you can use linear interpolation to calculate a "good enough" value to return.

Consider the first wave table the have. It plays C4 when you use a cursor with an increment of 1. If you make the increment 0.5 and use linear interpolation, the values that you would be returning would be the same as contents of your table that is an octave lower.

But you could chose any increment value, and even change it over time (to get glissandos).

The exact size of the increment for the cursor will depend on the size of the wave table and the sample rate as well as the desired pitch.

I am using wavetables for an FM synthesizer I coded. The sine wave table has 1024 increments for a single wave, float resolution. It seems to be working well. Sounds are quite clear--definitely less quantization noise than I get with my old Yamaha DX7 or the second generation DX7S.

Here is the code I'm currently using for returning the wave table value for a given cursor value, using linear interpolation:

```
public static float get(float i)
{
    final int idx = (int)i;
    
    return data[idx + 1] * (i - idx) 
            + data[idx] * ((idx + 1) - i);
}
```

The *data* table is a `float[]` of length 1025, while the *period* is 1024 steps. I have `data[0] == data[1024]` so that the above algorithm works for any cursor value in the range `0 <= cursor < 1024`. When the cursor equals or exceeds 1024, I subtract 1024. This way, one can increment the cursor indefinitely, creating a tone of any duration.

Comment: Thank your for the code. It was really useful to get it to work ;) and it can be implemented in javascript too and that's a huge plus for cross platform

Comment: Glad to help! If you get something going in Javascript, I'd be interested in seeing/hearing it. I'd like to leverage more of the audio coding I've done with Java more directly onto the web.